# Share OneNote Meeting Notes for Recurring Meetings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016

I want to share meeting notes in a OneNote notebook on a Sharepoint for a recurring meeting. Inserting the onenote link via the "Share Notes" button creates just a single link to a single page that remains the same for all the occurrences. This is not useful. Can Outlook generate a new link to a occurrence-specific OneNote page, and how do I access this? I run MS Office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer, it is not possible.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/share-meeting-notes-in-onenote-for-recurring/65fc8312-d6ea-4d2d-b722-6ae4d8b061ca

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the page, you can "Show Page Versions" this can be used as minutes for each individual meeting.